# Scale UIWebView content

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I would like to ask you about a problem that I'm facing with a project. The problem is that i'm trying to show a `UIWebView` control, I'm loading a video streaming into the web view , this is the code:

```
if(self.cameraUrl != nil) {
    let url = NSURL (string: self.cameraUrl!)
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    self.view_webvideo.loadRequest(requestObj)
    self.view_webvideo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
    let zoom = self.view_webvideo.bounds.size.width / self.view_webvideo.scrollView.contentSize.width
    self.view_webvideo.scrollView.setZoomScale(zoom, animated: true)
}
```

As you could see in the code I had research about that and try a lot of things but i can't scale the content, the video have `width=360` and `height=640`, I can't change the video size because it is a third party service.

Also i'm using the property: `Scales Page To Fit = true`

I want the video scale to fix into the webview component and don't show any scroll

I hope somebody could help me with that.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Have you tried to use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to call javascript code?

Comment: No I haven't tried this yet, i will do it and see what happen, thank you

Comment: Thank you @manman that works for me, but the first time the WebView the video isn't scale, but i will try to solve this, thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the last three lines with this (similar to what manman said)

```
self.view_webvideo.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].style.width='100%'")
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you both @kabiroberai for your help, only i have a problem it is the first time that the WebView load don't scale to 100% i have to change the device position and then the video scale, i tried reload() but don't work neither, but thank you all it is very useful answer

Comment: Add this to your `viewDidAppear` method and then it should work.

Comment: thank you very much, it is perfect... You help me a lot

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera no problem :)